# Blur background of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to **blur the background** of a `div`. I can only find solutions that apply to images as background, not HTML elements. It is for mobile use so CSS3 is not a problem. I have put a [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GhrUD/) together showing my dilema.

**My desired result:** When the dropdown appears, it blurs the content of *all the elements directly behind it*, not the entire page.

Here is the `HTML` for example purposes from the JSFiddle:

### HTML

```html
<a href="#" id="link">open/close</a>
<div id="slide">
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
     <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
     <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
     <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
</div>
<div id="page_content">
    <p>Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images </p>
     <p>Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images </p>
     <p>Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images </p>
     <p>Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images </p>
</div>
```

**EDITED:13:00 18/06/2013**

I tried to get the "accepted answer" to work but for some reason it doesn't work when extracted from the JSfiddle

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {


$('#link').click(function() {
  $('#slide').slideToggle('slow', function() {
  });
});

$('#main-view').click(function(){

html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width: 300,
        height: 100
    });
    
    $('#cover').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        $('#partial-overlay').slideToggle();
    });
});
});
</script>

<style>
#link {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}  
#partial-overlay {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:99; 
  }
canvas{
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-filter:blur(2px);
}
#cover{
    display:none;
    height:99px;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#main-view {
 width:300px;   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-view">
    <a href="#" id="link">open/clode</a>
  Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images page_content Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, not images Page content, 
</div>
    <div id="cover"></div>
<div id="partial-overlay">
    <p>Some content here</p>
    <p>Some content here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried with and without the DOM ready wrapper

Comment: try this jq plugin http://blurjs.com/, iam not sure if u can achiev blur effect with css

Comment: http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/

Check this article

Comment: This isn't blurring the background div, but looks similar - http://jsfiddle.net/GhrUD/1/

Comment: Lots of point-hungry copiers below :p

Comment: I have tried blur.js but this only works for images. Is implies it works for html elements but this is not the case, strickly images only. That is why It does not suit my needs.

Comment: Aravind30790 shows how to blur an element below, but that's only how to blur an actual element - not the things behind it.  That's not possible with html & css.  Opacity and a white background *is* the best you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. I use the canvas element. I suspect this will become very popular with the new pending release of iOS7 that makes use of this effect.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/TfWs3/49/

```
$('#main-view').click(function(){
html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width: 300,
        height: 100
    });

    $('#cover').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        $('#partial-overlay').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: even after closing i can see the blur , how to remove that

Comment: It works in JS fiddle but not once extracted from the fiddle. I know it's my error and not your code, i'm just struggling to find where i'm going wrong. I've edited my answer to show the code I've extracted from your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Altough it's not really a blur, but adding a white background with an alpha value will do the trick (`background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)`). Experiment with the alpha value for the best results.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GhrUD/6/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GhrUD/7/) (the second one has a grayish background on the content so you can see what happens).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'd like purely a blurred background with no overlay as such. I thought I could try and create a blurred background png image for the div but this also did not work.

Comment: You're welcome. The blurred background also won't work in case your content changes, right? I'm not sure this is possible with html and css, but I hope you'll find a way.

Answer (score -1):

Create a overlay for the image. under css code is for reference

```
.overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #A5A5A5;
    display: block;
    height: 231px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    padding: 9px 0px 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 298px;   
}
```