# jquery dense text shadow and blurred background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I am looking for a way/demo to make extra dense thick text shadow by **jquery** (cross browser compatible as jquery is.) that might **not be possible by simple css.**  with IE support

   multiple shadows cover it a bit though. but the problem is I think old browser compatibility issue. and jQuery covers it. thats why wanting a jQuery way.
2. Simple **background** transparency is easy and simple in css, but making the background color also with a transparent and **blurry effect** so that the picture (or anything) at the back most is not clearly visible

---

Important:

I need cross browser compatibility and support for some old browsers, so thats why I choosed jQuery over css

---

**May be just like in windows 7 title bar?**

I saw both of the above in the past but unfortunately I cant remember where.

If anyone knows a way or demo, I will be grateful.

Note: I do NOT want the css based background or text shadow.
sample text shadow that i found a bit close to what i want. its minimum dense though of what i wanted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know you don't want text-shadow, but this works alright: `.blur {
   color: black;
   text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}`

Comment: no no. this has css limits on shadow intensity. thats what my problem is

Comment: [You can apply multiple text-shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow).

Comment: see important section in edit

Comment: I'd skip the "old browsers": just build for the new ones with CSS3, it's not often that you've got time working on your side. Otherwise, in 2-3 years, you're going to have old useless code that you'll have to remove.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, jQuery uses CSS to do such things. So if an old browser doesn't support a specific feature in CSS, jQuery probably won't have a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more cross-browser implementation of the CSS with stacked shadows!

```
.blur { 
    color: black;

    /* Chrome, Firefox 3.5+, IE 10+, Opera 9+, Safari 1+ */
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);

   /* The webkit implementations to support more SOME older browsers */
   -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
   -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
   -khtml-text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

You can use a comma delimited list for text shadows to achieve what you need.

**REGARDING THE BLURRING OF A DIV**

FOUND SOMETHING AWESOME!

http://www.blurjs.com/

If that doesn't work, here is a stack overflow answer.

[Blur background of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147029/blur-background-of-a-div)

This method uses HTML5, and unfortunately won't be compatible with super old browsers.  Esentially the div needs to be aware of the background and overlay a blurred version of that background on top.

Comment: As far as IE goes, it likely won't work for <= IE9, but give it a try!

Comment: yes. thanks for the nice answer, some answers already stated it. but the main problem I have is the blur div one now

Comment: Plus one for nice answer but it has some problem . thats actually the one i took the image from :) earlier. http://blurjs.com/simpledemo.html

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently possible, but only on WebKit browsers, through

```
-webkit-filter: blur(123px);
filter: blur(123px);
```

[See this demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) and adjust the blur property.

Comment: here is a question about support for other browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803122/filter-blur1px-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie-and-opera

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is easy to do using simple CSS3, just stack up the shadows to make them more intense. Might be a better solution somewhere, but this works well and is easy to do. Also, if you use Less/Stylus you can make a function out of it to control text shadow intensity even better.

```
.blur { color: black; text-shadow: 0 0 5pt black, 0 0 10pt black, 0 0 15pt black; }
```

As for the blurred background, I see another answer has already solved that :)

Comment: very true, but the problem is I think old browser compatibility issue. and jQuery covers it. thats why wanting a jQuery way.